# Checking date issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

I'm trying really hard to do some date validation. I have created like 3 different functions, they all work but not in special cases.

The last thing I did was this:

```
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'd/m/Y'){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

I got this function from php site, and like I thought it worked better than mine I replaced it.

The date format the user has to input is dd/mm/YYYY and in the database format is yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

When i enter this invalid date: 30/30/1996 the function recognizes it as a valid date. Then I have this other function to explode the "/" and to make it like the database format with "-" and in that function it gives me the error:

**DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1996-30-30) at position 6 (0): Unexpected character'**

```
public function explodingDates($date){      
    list($day,$month,$year) = explode('/', $date);
    $newDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
    return (new \Datetime($newDate));
}
```

I'm burning my brain here, don't know what else to do for the validation. It also has to be prepared to receive any kind of input (like "askhdakjdh", "123213", "1.25/269") and return an invalid date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Fred-ii- In short: *shouln't*. Are you suggesting assign to an expression ?

Comment: There is a '\' in the return is that a typo?

Comment: @Fred-ii- why public is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't explode date strings. Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create the DateTime object, and use the `format()` method to convert it into a different format:

```
function ConvertToMySQLDate($datestr) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $datestr);
    $valid = $d && $d->format('d/m/Y') == $datestr;
    if ($valid) {
        return $d->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The above function accepts a date string in the format `dddd-mm-yyyy`, checks if it is valid, and returns the date in MySQL format (`yyyy-mm-dd`). It returns false if the supplied date is not valid.

Example usage:

```
var_dump(ConvertToMySQLDate('30/30/1996')); // bool(false)
var_dump(ConvertToMySQLDate('13/12/1996')); // string(10) "1996-12-13"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101710)

Comment: what about future dates? I have tried this and works with all I mentioned. But date: 28/03/2014 is giving me an error

Comment: @Limon: What error does it give you? It [works fine for me](https://eval.in/101712).

Comment: @amal, Please explain what this line mean. I could not get structure. $d && $d->format('d/m/Y') == $datestr. Will this be considered as If loop ?

Comment: @Pravin: It means, set `$valid` to the result of the query "*whether $d is True and the value of `$d->format('d/m/Y')` equals the value of `$datestr`*". So `$valid` will contain a boolean value of whether the supplied date conforms to the supplied format or not.